# Adding db_table to model added a last_login field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Background: I started a project with a custom User model. However, noob that I am, I was unaware of the AbstractBaseUser class. So I just wrote my own. The app has been deployed to prod and working fine. But now I want to switch to using AbstractBaseUser so I can take advantage of some of the built-in Django utilities (like the pre-made password resetting process). I had done this with a different app and it worked fine. But that one wasn't in prod while I made the change. Because this one is, I needed to keep the old user table while I made the changes with a copy of it. So my first step was to add `db_table = test_users` to my old user model, so as to keep the prod app running with an unchanged table. I ran the migration, and two unexpected things happened (I'm a noob, and that's why they were unexpected):

- The old user table was renamed. I thought a new table would be created. No problem, I quickly copied the new table and named the copy with the old table's name so the prod app could still find its users
- A column last_login was added. Why??
  Here's my model, with the added `db_table`

```
    class User(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        client_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_super = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = "test_users"
```

The big problem with this is that when I change to `AbstractBaseUser` and run the migration, I get an error. Looking at the migration file I see that this change creates a migration that all it tries to do is to add `last_login` to the table. So, of course, the error I get is "Duplicate column name 'last_login'"

So, my question is two-fold:

1. Why was that column added in the first migration?
2. If I just run `migrate --fake` and keep going, will it have unintended consequences? I thought this could be a good solution, given that the migration file shows nothing else is being done, and if the field already exists, then no harm done?

Comment: did you put both 'User' Classes into same file?

Comment: I don't have two User classes. I added the `db_table` to the existing User class. And then replaced `models.Model` with `AbstractBaseUser`. I also added a couple of additional things to make the modified User model work with its parent class, like `USERNAME_FIELD` and `REQUIRED_FIELDS`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you've changed the parent class django automatically change all the migrations that connected to your user class

Comment: No, the column last_login was added to the table when I changed the name of the table. **Before** I tried to change the parent class. In fact, the migration that I tried to do after changing the parent class fails _because_ of what the previous one did.